# What does this error about the Google chrome stable repository mean?

Tags: apt, 20.04, google-chrome, repository

```
skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Why is it displayed after `apt update`?

How can I make this disappear?

Comment: Who knows you gave no info to help you. What version of Ubuntu? What did you do to get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this is because your system has 32bit i386 architecture enabled (most amd64 64bit installs do).  And the Google repositories do NOT contain i386 packages.

You can fix this message showing up by editing the `apt` source definition to be `deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main` which will suppress the error because it tells the system that this repository ONLY has amd64 packages in it - which means it won't attempt to fetch the 32bit packages data.

Find the file that contains this line by running `grep -r 'dl.google.com' /etc/apt/`, and find the file path containing this item, you'll get output like this:

```
$ grep -r 'dl.google.com' /etc/apt/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save:deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main #Google Chrome (Stable)
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main #Google Chrome (Stable)
```

We don't care about any `.save` files for now.

Whatever that file is that's not the .save file (in my case, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`), edit it so the contents are as follows:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Save the file, and `apt` will now only retrieve `amd64` packages.

Answer (score 1):

It's displayed because you have 32-bit architecture enabled (most folks do) in addition the typical 64-bit.

That particular source doesn't offer 32-bit packages, only 64-bit. Hence the '*skipping 32-bit*' message.

Comment: My answer goes beyond and actually gives a *solution* so they don't see this anymore.